# Forloop results and iterate class names

Tags: php, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to create a `forloop` using Shopify's Liquid syntax that will count the returned results of images from a particular product and iterate unique div classes in each instance so that I can use these classes as anchors for a `scrollto` animation.

Currently, I'm trying something like:

```
 <ul class="scroll-to-nav>
 {% for image in product.images %}
   <li class="scroll-to-nav-link><a href="#link">link</a></li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

The desired outcome would be something like:

```
<ul class="scroll-to-nav>
 <li class="scroll-to-nav-link-1><a href="#link-1">link 1</a></li>
 <li class="scroll-to-nav-link-2><a href="#link-2">link 2</a></li>
 <li class="scroll-to-nav-link-3><a href="#link-3">link 3</a></li>
 <li class="scroll-to-nav-link-4><a href="#link-4">link 4</a></li>
 <li class="scroll-to-nav-link-5><a href="#link-5">link 5</a></li>
 etc etc etc
</ul>


<img src="path-to-img.jpg" id="link-1">
<img src="path-to-img.jpg" id="link-2">
<img src="path-to-img.jpg" id="link-3">
<img src="path-to-img.jpg" id="link-4">
<img src="path-to-img.jpg" id="link-5">
etc etc etc
```

Comment: Please read about forloops and how can you get the index here: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/for-loops

Comment: @drip it's the counting of results from the forloop and using them to create new class names to each result that I am having trouble with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Drip specified in comment, information is available in documentation. Here is a way to achieve what you want to do:

```
{% for image in product.images %}
  <a href="#" id="link{{ forloop.index }}">Link {{ forloop.index }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

If you need to get the length of your loop, you may use {{ forloop.length }}.